# Does SEO count on SO? Question closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-answers

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711779/difference-between-new-object-with-or-without-execute-brackets) has been closed for being a duplicate. Conceptually the question is a duplicate of another.

However my question has a different title to the question it is replicating. The question I have duplicated uses pseudocode as a title. Having searched google and then S.O. I could not find an answer. I cannot imagine typing meta pseudocode in to Google or S.O.'s search to find an exact hit.

Why close a question, a question which recieves 6 up-votes and 1 favorite within minutes. I have received my answer so there is nothing I have to gain in this*. What are the advantages to closing this question? My initail thoughts on see *closed* are: was I lazy? am I inexperienced? am I using S.O. wrong.

Comment: [Related](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: You shouldn't see "Closed as duplicate" as a "you shouldn't have asked the question", more as a "Look there, this might help you".

Comment: @Cody, not *whining* about votes.

Comment: @Cody, ok, I understand that. Sorry if my question seems like a complaint. It is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question is considered duplicate of another question not because the title, but because what the question is asking. Using a different title doesn't make the question a different one.

Normally, duplicate questions are not deleted, and the reason is also that a duplicate question helps to find the original question; that is the reason why, when a question is closed as duplicate, a comment is automatically added to the duplicating question to redirect the users to the original question.

Asking a question that is duplicate of another one can happen, especially if the other question is using a title that could not seem related to the question being asked.

Answer (score 5):

It's much more common that the problem with SEO and dupes is the complete opposite: SEO is hurt because there are too many duplicates, and so no single question ever earns enough page rank by itself to climb in the search results.

Also remember that closed is not gone.  Your question, with it's accepted answer, will still be listed in Google, and now any user who shows up from Google will also have a convenient to another similar question that may include additional information.

Comment: good point that the question is not lost to google. however SEO would only be *hurt* if the page ranking advantage was links pointing to the article. There is the possiblity that search terms are adventitious to a users search request.